# White line appears between the tiles using ImageMosaic / ImagePyramid technique on GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I have created image Pyramid of 4 levels using gdal retile and published it on GeoServer using ImagePyramid technique. When I am accessing it in QGIS, it seems to work fine but at the zoom level from 1:2000 to 1:900. I am getting some white line between the tiles.[image]

also, I have published each folder of pyramid separately on Geoserver using image mosaic technique. when I am accessing these layers in Qgis. in folder layer 0, 2 and 4 I haven't found the white lines between tiles at any zoom level.[image]
 but when I am loading folder layer 1, whites lines are appearing between the tiles at the same zoom level.
I have also tried the "Input/output Transparent Color" set to white but it's not helpful.

Can anybody suggest why white lines appear and how to remove it?

Comment: Do you use gdal_retile.py? Try to add a small overlap. There should be no need to use overlap but there may be a bug in gdal_retile.